# Two different adUnit ID from two accounts

Tags: android, admob

I have an application,can I use two different ad id from two different accounts in a single app?? 
I just want to know if this will cause any violation to the policies or not.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. But an AdView can only hold a single AdUnitId at any point in time, so you will need to programmatically swap the AdUnitIds, at which point the new AdUnitId takes effect.

You don't explain your use case. But I suspect you are attempting to share ad revenue between 2 developers. If so, the best way of doing this is to randomly assign the AdUnitId when the app starts up.

Answer (score -1):

yes, you can use but not for one Ad Object or Interstitial Ad Object both add unit ,but you require to define different  - different  Ad Object. with different  id,
like following

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:visibility="gone"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id_1" />




<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:visibility="gone"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id_2" />
```

I am here describe you because you mentioned In Single App.

Comment: okay but i have to give the link of the apps in two different account of admob so will that cause problem?

Comment: not any dependency admob account with application until you not link app with your admob project or adunit .

Comment: Have you not tested by putting the link in admob account?

Comment: No, but without link i have tested.

Comment: Is it necessary to link the app of playstore with admob account?

Comment: No, this is not necessary,

Comment: I have running app without link.